# Omitting "and" and using participle instead

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, commas, participles

> I was working a drug case, ***tracking*** this drug dealer for months.
>   Then suddenly he disappeared. (From a tv-series)

This sentence kind of confused me. In this sentence, what does participle imply? (the result of the main clause or an action that happens at time same time as main clause's action or describing the subject of the main clause?)

How can I rewrite this sentence? As:

> 1- I was working a drug case ***and I was tracking*** this drug dealer
>   for months. Then suddenly he disappeared.
>
> 2- I was working a drug case ***and tracking*** this drug dealer for
>   months. Then suddenly he disappeared.
>
> 3- I was working a drug case ***and I tracked*** this drug dealer for
>   months. Then suddenly he disappeared.

Can I omit "subject + be + verb" and use comma + participle ?

For example:

> 4- I was reading a book ***and I was*** ***listening*** to some music.
>
> 4a- I was reading a book ***and listening*** to some music.
>
> 4b- I was reading a book, ***listening*** to some music.

Comment: The tracking activity, was part of the drug case activity. It would be more akin to *I was reading a book, turning the pages as I went* rather than doing two seperate things

Comment: @Smock Thank you :). Can we say basically, these two actions happens at the same time period? + Could you give your opinion on the first three sentences? (How can I rewrite that sentence I quoted from a tv-series?) + (How would you rewrite your example without using participle "I was reading a book, turning the pages as I went")